# Using svg in btimap

Tags: android, svg, drawable

This is my splash screen background and this works fine

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:drawable="@color/background_splash_screen"/>

    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_logo" />
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

But whenever I replaced

```
 android:src="@drawable/ic_logo" />
```

with

```
 android:src="@drawable/some svg image" />
```

it gets me error 
How can I use svg in src bitmap?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Hi Android don't support svg format directly. You can import the svg to the vectorial format supported by Android platform. You can use the Android Studio's Asset Studio plugin:

You can import the asset from svg, you can right clicking over the drawable source directory and chose the new -> Vector Asset  and in this windows with tittle : Asset Studio you can chose the Asset Type: Local ( SVG;PSD )

**Warning**: Not all standards features of SVG are supported in Android vector language:

You can check the section: support and restrictions for SVG files in this official  page:

https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio?

And in the xml you can add the vector asset without the bitmap tag:

```xml
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:drawable="@color/background_splash_screen"/>

    <item
        android:src="@drawable/ic_vector_logo"/>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: I already import the svg image but the problem is whenever I replaced the png with svg it gets error

Comment: Oh you can use only item with svg you can test this approach ?